# How to access inside frame

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, xss

How to access into iframe:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('sitefield1');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var elem = innerDoc.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
```

Main page is test1.ru, iframe is test2.ru (both on my computer). In .htaccess is

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://test1.ru/2"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-InlineCount"
```

Is it possible to get inside the iframe module?
I am owner of this web sites (do some testing) and can also add any settings to my firefox. 
What I found also that this code do not work in IE (even that I turn on acceess beween different domains and XSS filter is turned off). Chrome looks like do not support --disable-web-security anymore... Chrome's error is 
*Blocked a frame with origin "test1" from accessing a frame with origin "test2". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.*

Any ideas will be very helpful to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly access frames across origins. In modern browsers you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

The frame sending the data needs to call `postMessage`

```
top.postMessage({ foo: "bar" }, "*");
```

and the frame receiving the data needs to register an event listener to look for messages and react to them.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(evt) {
    alert(event.data.foo);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I can access frame from the same web site, isn't it? So the technology is available, but the only problem is the SOP. Do you know any modern web brousers that allow to turn this off? Does Access-Control-Allow-Origin make any difference?